# How do I display the user's name before the their email address when sending PHP mail?

Tags: php, email

For example in the Gmail application, when clicking "show details" there would be

"To: whatever@gmail.com". What I want is to show a full name before that,
 for example:"My Name whatever@gmail.com".

I think I would have to add something within `$to = "whatever@gmail.com"`. Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: It's in the mail manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thank you for that, it is quite helpful.

Comment: What does your code look like? Are you using an email library or the built in mail function? the answer will look differently depending on what you're using.

Comment: My code is very standard as it uses the mail function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/paste from the docs:

```
$to_name = "Mary";
$to_address = "mary@example.com";
// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: '.$to_name.' <'.$to_address.'>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>'; // <-- this is what you want?
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how to change "Mary" and the email to variables? As in the correct syntax.

Comment: Dude, that is basic PHP strings concat. Check my update

Comment: No problem, enjoy learning. But also learn to check the docs by yourself, it's a must

Answer (score 1):

If you have the IMAP extension you can use [imap_rfc822_write_address()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-write-address.php).

```
echo imap_rfc822_write_address("hartmut", "example.com", "Hartmut Holzgraefe");
```

Or you can just wing it and hope everyone uses "safe" email addresses.

```
echo "$name <$email>";
```

The actual header would be:

```
To: NameHere <email@example.com>\r\n
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful as well! Will get into security stuff when I get better!